# Цикл выводит только первое значение

Tags: php, циклы

Вот мой код, я пытаюсь просто сформировать массив объектов. 
sizeof($vuzes) = 900, но почему то выводится только первое значение...

```
$mappings = [];

for($i=0; $i<sizeof($vuzes); $i++) {


    $url = "http://url.com/".$vuzes[$i]["Logo"];
    list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($url);

    $map = [
        "logo" => $vuzes[$i]["Logo"],
        "height" => $height,
        "width" => $width,
    ];

    print($i); var_dump($map);

    $mappings.push($map);


}
```

2 часа сижу разбираюсь не могу понять..

Comment: В php есть функция `array_push` вы не можете наполнять массив через `.push`, а лучше вообще используйте `$mappings[] = $map;`

Comment: или $map[] = [ "logo" .....